# Exporting latin1 database and import as utf8 / convert to utf8

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am working on a website that uses an old database, running on aa external MySQL 4.1 server (Server A). The database uses a latin1_swedish_ci collation, as do the tables and columns. There is a new server B that runs MySQL 5 to replace server A. The encoding should be utf8_unicode_ci.

1. I export the DB on Server A:
   `mysqldump -u root -p --opt --quote-names --skip-set-charset --default-character-set=latin1 db_a -r db_a.sql`
2. Transfer db_a.sql via scp from server A to server B
3. Replace latin1 with utf-8
   `sed -e 's/CHARSET\=latin1/CHARSET\=utf8\ COLLATE\=utf8_general_ci/g' db_a.sql > db_a2.sql`
4. Convert file to utf-8
   `iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 db_a2.sql > db_a3.sql`
5. Import db_a3.sql

In phpmyadmin everything is printed correctly. But the new client application shows artifacts in the text columns.

I tried different variations of the steps above without success. Including importing as latin1 and using the mysql convert command. Does someone know a solution to my problem?

Comment: If phpmyadmin print correctly, it seems it is a problem of the other client. Maybe encoding was hardcoded, or maybe the pages are generated as latin1, so browser interpret the UTF-8 as latin1 (because of webserver)

Comment: To debug encoding problems, you should write the byte codes of a know character (and the know value), before, after (just a simple query) and on web. This helps understanding where the problem is. "Wrong character" do not help. Knownig which/how tell us about common mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Better would be to load it up as latin1, *then* fix things.

However, this is not straightforward because there are multiple scenarios to consider.  See this:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases
Note in particular that there are at least 2 different ways to do the `ALTER`.  If you pick the wrong one, the data will become garbled worse.

To see what you have, use this for a sample of the data:

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...
```